# XML two tags with the same name

Tags: xml

In my XML document I have two tags with the same name, both are called item, I have now created an XML schema for this document, considering that I have two tags with the same name, is my XML schema accurate?

XML document

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 

<shiporder orderid="889923" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="shiporder.xsd"> 
    <orderperson>John Smith</orderperson> 
        <shipto> 
            <name>Ola Nordmann</name> 
            <address>Langgt 23</address> 
            <city>4000 Stavanger</city> 
            <country>Norway</country> 
        </shipto> 
        <item> <!--First Item Tag-->
            <title>Empire Burlesque</title> 
            <note>Special Edition</note> 
            <quantity>1</quantity> 
            <price>10.90</price> 
        </item> 
        <item> <!--Second Item Tag-->
            <title>Hide your heart</title> 
            <quantity>1</quantity> 
            <price>9.90</price> 
        </item>
```

XML Schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"> 

<xs:element name="shiporder">
    <xs:complexType >
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="orderperson"/>
            <xs:element name="shipto">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                    `   <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="item"> <!--Only 1 item tag defined in the schema-->
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="title" type="xs:stri+ng"/>
                                        <xs:element name="note" type="xs:string"/>
                                        <xs:element name="quantity" type="xs:integer"/>
                                        <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal"/>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Are there any error messages when you validate your Xml document against your Xml schema?

Comment: Actually you didn't define an `item` but `items` in the schema.

Comment: the only error message I am getting is  Element 'xs:sequence' can not have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only. Line 25

Comment: fixing items to item, does that mean the schema is accurate?

Comment: Shouldn't you define the item element outside the shipto element? At least your document instance seems to mean so. Also, you might want to define an items element to hold the individual items.

Comment: So I should close the shipto element first in the schema? is that what you are saying?

Comment: Go to this site paste your XML in and it will build you an XSD for free http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html#ad-output

Comment: Yes, close the 'shipto' element and then define 'item' if you want the 'item' elements to occur outside the 'shipto' (matching your instance document). Actually, an 'items' wrapper element is not strictly necessary, but it might help you in parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match your XML instance, you should make some changes in your XML Schema.

(I'm assuming you wanted to declare `item` and not `items`.)

First, you are defining `item` as a child element of `shipto` when I believe (from your XML instance and from the meaning of the tags) it should probably be at the same level:

```
 <xs:element name="shiporder">
    <xs:complexType >
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="orderperson"/>
            <xs:element name="shipto">
               ...
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="item">
               ...
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:element>
```

To allow more than one `item` you can declare `maxOccurs="unbounded"` or define a lower limit:

```
<xs:element name="item" maxOccurs="unbounded">
```

You also need to declare the attribute in `shiporder`. It should be done in the `complexType` definition:

```
<xs:element name="shiporder">
    <xs:complexType >
        <xs:sequence>
          ...
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="orderid" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Finally, you have to decide whether `note` is optional or not. If it's optional, then declare

```
<xs:element name="note" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
```

since the default is `1`. If it's not optional, then you have to include it in your XML instance otherwise it will not validate.

Comment: amazing answer thanks for that, just one problem during validation I keep getting this: Element 'xs:sequence' can not have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only. says error is on line 15 - I made all the changes you said, also in my XML document do I have to declare schema twice?

Comment: That's true. There shouldn't be any characters inside `<xs:sequence>`. Only elements. Maybe there's some character there by mistake.

Comment: In the XML you pasted here there is a backtick character `\`` just before the first `<xs:element>`