# How to have two identical elements in a .xsd

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have an .xsd document used at my place of work and I have to add a employer object to the .xsd document used to verify the XML before attempting the upload.

Here is a sample

```
<xs:element name="shop">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation> The attribute id is an integer value</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="name"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Above you see that their is an element that references name.

The definition for which is provided below

`<xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>`

```
<xs:element name="employer">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="name"/>
            <xs:element ref="street" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element ref="city" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element ref="prov" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element ref="postalcode" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element ref="phone"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Since I cannot define another name attribute to reference, then how am I supposed to get around this? If I try to declare another one it says I cannot because the name attribute already exists.

I even tried moving the duplicate attribute to the bottom to see if the .xsd could use the attribute for both references, and I get an error stating that "name" is not defined at Runtime.

Resources:

 [https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/XSD-XML-Schema-Definition#:~:text=XSD%20(XML%20Schema%20Definition)%20is,Markup%20Language%20(XML)%20document](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/XSD-XML-Schema-Definition#:%7E:text=XSD%20(XML%20Schema%20Definition)%20is,Markup%20Language%20(XML)%20document).

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_intro.asp

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms757814(v=vs.85)

**When I tried this one below, I get an error in the Schema that says "The maxOccurs Attribute cannot be present"**

 [XML two tags with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22362616/xml-two-tags-with-the-same-name)

Most of the resources I have seen online seem to have to do with Windows configurations for Visual Studio and that is not the specific issue I am experiencing. Hoping someone here has something enlightening that I am just missing.

Thanks for any and all help.